# how to align the button at bottom in linear layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]I want to keep the adview layout at bottom in linear layout. i tried using gravity and layout_gravity at bottom but its not working,i had attached the code and snapshot too.
please give me any solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/linearmainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/inner_screen_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fbShare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/fb_btn"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/twitterShare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/tw_btn"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/revealButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/reveal_btn"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="320dip"
                android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/image5" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/correctMark"
                    android:layout_width="80dip"
                    android:layout_height="80dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/cleared_imag"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ticketCounterContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ticket1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ticket"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ticket2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ticket"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ticket3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ticket"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/movieName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/input_field"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="10dip" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/correctAnswerLayoutContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/movieName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_rectangle_white_background"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hintContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hintOne"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/musical_moview_text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hintTwo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/release_text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hintThree"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/hint3_text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/next_btn" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/publisher_id"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are using too complex design. I think weight in RelativeLayout is very bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/linearmainlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fbShare"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/twitterShare"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/revealButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/imageContainer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="60"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="320dip"
                    android:layout_height="150dip"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/correctMark"
                        android:layout_width="80dip"
                        android:layout_height="80dip"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ticketCounterContainer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/ticket1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/ticket2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/ticket3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/movieName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="10dip" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/correctAnswerLayoutContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/movieName"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/hintContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/hintOne"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="musical_moview_text"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/hintTwo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="release_text"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/hintThree"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="hint3_text"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/publisher_id"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the button and Adview in a new relative layout below the linear layouts.